# Async Operation using Spring Boot and Executors

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, java-8

I want to understand the difference between the two codes I am using Java and Springboot. Are they both equivalent -

a. Without using @Async and spawning a new thread/task an submitting to the taskexecutor
b. One that uses @Async along with the executor name

a.

```
public void executeNewThread() {    
        Thread t = new Thread( ()->{
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            //we are using nasa open API
            fetchNasaLocInfo();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    taskExecutor.execute(t);
}
```

b.

```
@Async("specificTaskExecutor")
public void executeAsync() {
        try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        //we are using nasa open API
        fetchNasaLocInfo();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These two links directly from Spring probably provide a sufficient answer to your question.

- JavaDoc of [`@Async`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html)
- https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Basically, the annotated method with `@Async` is considered as an asynchronous method and should return either `Future` or its specification or `void`. The method runs in a thread taken from a specified executor service's thread pool (`@Async("specificTaskExecutor")`), which is usually provided as a bean:

```
@Bean(name = "specificTaskExecutor")
public TaskExecutor specificTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor specificTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    specificTaskExecutor.initialize();
    return specificTaskExecutor;
}
```